# Woocommerce minimum quantity based on user roles separated for each product

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, roles

I have set minimum quantity and step quantity for each product based on plugin "WooCommerce Min Max Quantity & Step Control Single". Plugin works great for B2B. I have hundreds of products and almost each has own quantities.
I need to disable minimum and step quantity for **

- unlogged and customer user roles

** and let standard B2C customers to order just 1 pc and not to force them to order full package.
I tried to create snippet for both ideas I have but they don't work.
Help please !

Disable plugin for role:

```
function deactivate_wppp_based_on_role() {
    global $current_user;
    if (in_array('customer', $current_user->roles)) {
        deactivate_plugins( '/woo-min-max-quantity-step-control-single/wcmmq.php' );
    } else { 
        activate_plugins( '/woo-min-max-quantity-step-control-single/wcmmq.php' );
    }
}
add_action('admin_init', 'deactivate_wppp_based_on_role');
```

Disable quantities for role:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_quantity_input_args', 'quantity_input_args_filter_callback', 10, 2 );
function quantity_input_args_filter_callback( $args ) {

$user = wp_get_current_user();
if ( in_array( 'customer', $user->roles ) ) {

}
        return $args;
}
```

Comment: Trying to disable the plugin dynamically, is most certainly not the way to go, I’d think. Plugins can hook into that, to perform certain clean-up actions etc., and if this plugin was doing anything like that, you likely would not want that to happen all the time.

Comment: agree, so how to force if guest or customer take 1pc min and 1pc step (standard) and only for others choose quantity from fields: _wcmmq_s_min_quantity and _wcmmq_s_product_step (fields belongs to plugin WooCommerce Min Max Quantity & Step Control Single)